# I don't care if she says no

Tags: usage, conditional-constructions, present-tense, present-continuous

When we want to say we don't care about something which may happen in the future. Should we use the simple present tense?

Let's say I am going to ask a girl out for the first time (I never asked her out before). In this situation, is the sentence **"I don't care if she says no. I am going to ask her out"** correct, or should I say something like **"I don't care if she is going to say no"** instead of **"I don't care if she says no"**?

Another example: Let's say I am going to a dangerous place, or I am generally not scared of death. In these contexts, can I say **"I don't care if I die"**, or should I say like "**I don't care if I am going to die"**?

I think I should use the version with simple present. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Either way works, though the simple present does sound more natural to my ear (I'm a native English-speaker).

I don't know if anyone would parse things out this way in ordinary usage, but using the *is going to* construction to express a future state gives an impression of inevitability. She may say no in the future either way, but *she is going to* gives a vague suggestion that she's already in the process of saying no while *if she says* keeps the emphasis on the conditional nature of the sentence.

Comment: But _is going to_ isn't (functionally speaking) a progressive at all. It's one of several ways to express future meaning, along with the _will_ modal (usually referred to bizarrely as "the future tense") and the so-called "present" (which is not used for present meaning apart from a restricted class of verbs, and special contexts such as narrative).

Comment: In specific usages I definitely agree, but the same construction does sometimes indicate progressive cases ("She *is going to* the mall, for example). That's why I presented things as I did, but I may be stepping all over my grammar. I'll edit the post and remove the tense name regardless, to make things clearer.

Comment: I absolutely agree that _is going to_ can be progressive; but in the idiom _is going to [verb]_ it isn't.

Comment: @FireandIce Note that in your examples you use **if** to mean **whether** (as native English speakers do all the time because it's quick and easy). It's only when English speakers learn a foreign language that requires different verb constructions after **if** and **whether** that most become aware of the difference.